# Reassigning a pointers reference in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

This has been driving me crazy and I feel like I have tried almost everything.

```
SDL_Surface * Cell::image=NULL;


//somewhere in main
Cell::LoadSurface(Cell::image, "image.bmp");

void Cell::LoadSurface(SDL_Surface * surf, char * filename)
{
 if(surf == NULL) 
 {
   SDL_Surface *temp;
   SDL_Surface **temp2 = &surf;
   temp = SDL_LoadBMP(filename);

   if(temp == NULL)
     printf("Cannot Load Image\n");
   else
     printf("Image Loaded\n");
   surf = SDL_DisplayFormat(temp);
   //*surf = *SDL_DisplayFormat(temp); //segfault

   Uint32 colorkey = SDL_MapRGB(surf->format, 0, 0, 0 );
   SDL_SetColorKey(surf, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY | SDL_RLEACCEL , colorkey);

   SDL_FreeSurface(temp);
 }
```

Image and LoadSurface are both static. Image always remain null no matter what is assigned to it or the program will terminate in a segfault, like in the commented line.

Thanks,

Comment: Retagged C++ as this is definitely not C code.

Answer (score 3):

Pass `surf` by reference to allow changes in `surf` reflected back to the input `Cell::image`.

```
void Cell::LoadSurface(SDL_Surface*& surf, char* filename) {
//                                 ^
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call LoadSurface, you are creating a copy of the (image) pointer.
You can either use a pointer reference:

```
void Cell::LoadSurface(SDL_Surface *& surf, char * filename)
```

Or use a pointer to pointer:

```
void Cell::LoadSurface(SDL_Surface ** surf, char * filename)
```

Note that in the later you will need to change the call to:

```
Cell::LoadSurface(&Cell::image, "image.bmp");
```

And change the LoadSurface to treat surf as a pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer addresses are copied when passed to function calls.  That means when you call within the function

```
surf = SDL_DisplayFormat(temp);
```

you are actually only overwriting the copy of the Cell::image address.

To fix this you must pass in the address of the Cell::image pointer, so you know which memory address to update with the new pointer value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your responses, I really appreciate all your help.

But as it turns out, a pointer reference for the SDL_Surface struct cannot be made. Due to the fact SDL_Surface contains other other pointers. I restructured my code accordingly (to instead return a SDL_Surface). Which makes this is more of an SDL related issue than a c++ related issue.